# Using <dl> for one item?

Tags: html

I wanted to see if it was practical to use a definition list for only one item.  What I'm doing is presenting data in a grid and each column will have it's own data to present.  I would assume i would need to put a  tag in each column.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="column-1">
        <dl>
            <dt>Name</dt>
            <dd>Jack</dd>
        </dl>
   </div>
   <div class="column-1">
        <dl>
            <dt>Company</dt>
            <dd>Some Company</dd>
        </dl>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using it formatting purposes which is the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually just found out about the <dl> tag and was wondering the best way to present data in columns.  I will keep looking..